# How do I get all the values from one column in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a result set which has rows(first row is heading) and columns (like dataset in .NET). I want to fetch all the values from one column out of from that result set. How can I achieve it. I am doing it by in below way.

```
if (r.length)//r is my result set {
  r.forEach(element => {
    const featureCode = element.column_name.filter();
    // Here I am trying to fetch column name value from r using for each loop
    return featureCode; 
  }
```

Am I doing it right or there is a better way to do it?

### My result set r is look like below.

Hi,

My data in r will look like below.

```
[
  {
    "Col1": "abc",
    "Col2": "pqr",
    "Col3": "xyx",
    "Col4": "aaa",
    "Col5": "bbb",
    "Col6": "ccc",
    "Col7": "ddd"
  },
  {
    "Col1": "aaa",
    "Col2": "bbb",
    "Col3": "ccc",
    "Col4": "ddd",
    "Col5": "eee",
    "Col6": "fff",
    "Col7": "ggg"
  },
]
```

Comment: please share what your data looks like and how you want it to look like

Comment: you don't need to loop through the result if its just one element Array, just use `r[0]` if this is what you want.

Comment: @mamounothman I need all the values from that column. Will r[0] give all the values or only for 1 row,

Comment: I missed understood your question, it wasn't  clear to me, so if you want to have the first column of each row, just inside the `foreach` do `const featureCode = element.column1`.

Comment: @mamounothman I have updated a question.

Comment: Looks like you want to remove the first item of `r`? 
If so, just do `r.shift()` before your `forEach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an ideal job for [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const r = [{
    Col1: "abc",
    Col2: "pqr",
    Col3: "xyx",
    Col4: "aaa",
    Col5: "bbb",
    Col6: "ccc",
    Col7: "ddd"
  },
  {
    Col1: "aaa",
    Col2: "bbb",
    Col3: "ccc",
    Col4: "ddd",
    Col5: "eee",
    Col6: "fff",
    Col7: "ggg"
  }
];

const colId = "Col5";
const colData = r.map(obj => obj[colId]);

console.log({ colData });
// { colData: [ 'bbb', 'eee' ] }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to loop through the array result and retrieve the value you want, just replace `Col1`, this is browser javascript but it will work for Node.js too.

```js
const r = [
  {
    "Col1": "abc",
    "Col2": "pqr",
    "Col3": "xyx",
    "Col4": "aaa",
    "Col5": "bbb",
    "Col6": "ccc",
    "Col7": "ddd"
  },
  {
    "Col1": "aaa",
    "Col2": "bbb",
    "Col3": "ccc",
    "Col4": "ddd",
    "Col5": "eee",
    "Col6": "fff",
    "Col7": "ggg"
  },
]
let temp= [];

if (r.length) {//r is my result set {
  r.forEach(({Col1}) => console.log(Col1));
}

// or this
if (r.length) {//r is my result set {
  r.forEach((elem) => consolelog(elem.Col1));
}

// or this

if (r.length) {//r is my result set {
  r.forEach(({Col1}) => temp.push(Col1));
}

console.log(temp)
```